# Retaining Group by character values in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, group-by, retain

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], 
    'B': ['sam', 'anu', 'rita', 'first', 'mid', 'last']})
print(df)
```

[image]

I have the data frame as above and I would like to convert is as below

[image]

Any help much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Try with

```
out = df.groupby('A',as_index=False).agg(tuple)
   A                   B
0  1    (sam, anu, rita)
1  2  (first, mid, last)
```